# como puedo pasar una variable en un archivo html a otro

Tags: javascript, html

Resulta que estoy haciendo una función de búsqueda. Primero se escribe lo que se quiere buscar en el `index.html` y luego la respuesta se la muestra en un archivo llamado `search.html`. Este es el código del index.html:

```js
// Scripts de búsqueda con indexOf

const formulary = document.querySelector('#input');
const result = document.querySelector('#resultado');
const divH1 = document.querySelector('#divh1');

let links = [
  {
    nombre: 'Página principal',
    link: 'index.html',
    href: 'Págína principal',
    text: '¡Hola! Bienvenido. Siéntete cómodo de estar aquí, te tenemos una sorpresa para tí...'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Sobre mí',
    link: 'aboutme.html',
    href: 'Sobre mí'
  }, // Pendiente el texto
  {
    nombre: 'Contacto',
    link: 'contact.html',
    href: 'Contacto',
    text: 'Rellene el siguiente formulario para ser respondido y ayudarle. Nuestro servicio se extiende por todo el Ecuador.'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Proyectos',
    link: 'projects/projects.html',
    href: 'Proyectos'
  }, // Pendiente el texto
  {
    nombre: 'D-grafix',
    link: 'projects/dgrafix.html',
    href: 'Proyectos | D-grafix'
  } // Pendiente el texto
]

const filter = () => {
  result.innerHTML = '';
  const text = formulary.value.toLowerCase();

  for (let link of links) {
    let nombre = link.nombre.toLowerCase();
    if (nombre.indexOf(text) !== -1) {
      result.innerHTML += `<li><i class="bi bi-search" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="${link.link}">${link.nombre} - ${link.href}</a><br><p class="lead mt-1 text-truncate" style="font-size:15px;max-width:350px;">${link.text}</p></li>`
    }
  }
  if (result.innerHTML === '') {
    result.innerHTML +=
      `<li>No se han encontrado resultados...</li>`
  }
}

formulary.addEventListener('input', () => {
  document.querySelector('#divh1').innerHTML += `<h1 class="display-6 my-5">Resultados para <mark>${formulary.value}</mark>:</h1>`
});

filter();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
       <div class="d-flex ms-auto">
       <form action="search.html" class="d-flex ms-auto">
        <input class="form-control me-2" id="input" name="s" type="search" placeholder="Busca algo..." aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success me-2" type="submit">Buscar</button>
        </form>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el de `search.html`:

```js
// Scripts de búsqueda con indexOf

const formulary = document.querySelector('#input');
const result = document.querySelector('#resultado');
const divH1 = document.querySelector('#divh1');

let links = [
  {
    nombre: 'Página principal',
    link: 'index.html',
    href: 'Págína principal',
    text: '¡Hola! Bienvenido. Siéntete cómodo de estar aquí, te tenemos una sorpresa para tí...'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Sobre mí',
    link: 'aboutme.html',
    href: 'Sobre mí'
  }, // Pendiente el t
  {
    nombre: 'Contacto',
    link: 'contact.html',
    href: 'Contacto',
    text: 'Rellene el siguiente formulario para ser respondido y ayudarle. Nuestro servicio se extiende por todo el Ecuador.'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Proyectos',
    link: 'projects/projects.html',
    href: 'Proyectos'
  }, // Pendiente el texto
  {
    nombre: 'D-grafix',
    link: 'projects/dgrafix.html',
    href: 'Proyectos | D-grafix'
  } // Pendiente el texto
]

const filter = () => {
  result.innerHTML = '';
  const text = formulary.value.toLowerCase();

  for (let link of links) {
    let nombre = link.nombre.toLowerCase();
    if (nombre.indexOf(text) !== -1) {
      result.innerHTML += `<li><i class="bi bi-search" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="${link.link}">${link.nombre} - ${link.href}</a><br><p class="lead mt-1 text-truncate" style="font-size:15px;max-width:350px;">${link.text}</p></li>`
    }
  }
  if (result.innerHTML === '') {
    result.innerHTML +=
      `<li>No se han encontrado resultados...</li>`
  }
}

formulary.addEventListener('input', () => {
  document.querySelector('#divh1').innerHTML += `<h1 class="display-6 my-5">Resultados para <mark>${formulary.value}</mark>:</h1>`
});

filter();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body
   <div class="container" id="formContainer">
       <h1 class="display-3 my-5">Búsqueda</h1>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="hero" id="divh1"></div> <!--Texto con el contenido: "Resultados de 'búsqueda'."-->
      </div>
      <div class="container mt-3 search">
        <div class="container"> 
          <ul id="resultado"></ul>
        </div>  
      </div> <!--Resultados de la búsqueda-->
   </div>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema es que la variable no la ve el search y se muestran siempre todas las respuestas en vez de lo que se ha buscado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente lo que intentas no tiene mucho sentido y de por si no es lo mas optimo, pues enrealidad estuve analizando y mirando bien el codigo y tratas de usar el `HTML` de un archivo en otro archivo `HTML` totalmente aparte del primero, que no hace falta decir que uno o ambos de los codigos fallara estrepitosamente por esta razón, de hecho tuve que reorganizar incluso tu código para poder que este funcionara, pues asi como se encuentra hay `HTML` que falta en una parte de la pagina y que se encuentra en la otra y asi sucesivamente, por ejemplo tuve que quitar esta parte:

```
const formulary = document.querySelector('#input');

formulary.addEventListener('input', () => {
  document.querySelector('#divh1').innerHTML += `<h1 class="display-6 my-5">Resultados para <mark>${formulary.value}</mark>:</h1>`
});
```

Debido a que en el codigo donde lo tienes (`index.html`) el elemento al que apuntas (`'#divh1'`) no existe, ya que este se encuentra en `'search.html'`, y pues... no hace falta decir que es innacesible ese elemento desde `index.html`.

Y en la funcion `filter` que hace parte del archivo `search.html` estabas haciendo algo que tampoco era posible, tratando de acceder al input de tipo `busqueda` desde el archivo `search.html`, pero ocurre el mismo problema...

> El input de tipo busqueda se encuentra en otro HTML por lo tanto es
> inaccesible...

si no me crees mira atentamente esta partes de la funcion `filter`:

```
//Mas arriba:
const formulary = document.querySelector('#input');

//Mas abajo
const filter = () => {
  ...
  const text = formulary.value.toLowerCase();   //ERROR
  ...
}
```

Por lo tanto tratabas de hacer algo que simplemente era imposible, y su resultado iba a ser siempre `undefined`.

Tambien me di cuenta de que en algunos objetos la propiedad `text` NO existe:

```
let links = [
  {
    nombre: 'Página principal',
    link: 'index.html',
    href: 'Págína principal',
    text: '¡Hola! Bienvenido. Siéntete cómodo de estar aquí, te tenemos una sorpresa para tí...'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Sobre mí',
    link: 'aboutme.html',
    href: 'Sobre mí'
  } // Pendiente el texto
}
```

Si esto no lo manejas bien va hacer que se te añada un `undefined` a tu texto cada vez que el `script` encuentre un objeto sin esa propiedad debido a la forma como construiste tu `html`:

```
result.innerHTML += `<li><i class="bi bi-search" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="${link.link}">${link.nombre} - ${link.href}</a><br><p class="lead mt-1 text-truncate" style="font-size:15px;max-width:350px;">${link.text}</p></li>`
```

La solucion a ello ya la inclui en mi respuesta completa, respuesta la cual veras completa mas abajo, pero en resumen en esta parte de aqui:

```
${link.text}
```

Debemos anadirle una condicion en caso de que la propiedad no exista y un valor por defecto, en este caso un string vacio:

```
${link.text || ''}
```

Sin mas que agregar este es el codigo que tengo ahora en el `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="d-flex ms-auto">
            <form action="search.html" class="d-flex ms-auto">
                <input class="form-control me-2" id="input" name="s" type="search" placeholder="Busca algo..." aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success me-2" type="submit">Buscar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y este es el archivo `search.html` y su `main.js`:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  // Scripts de búsqueda con indexOf
  const result = document.querySelector('#resultado');
  const divH1 = document.querySelector('#divh1');

  let links = [{
      nombre: 'Página principal',
      link: 'index.html',
      href: 'Págína principal',
      text: '¡Hola! Bienvenido. Siéntete cómodo de estar aquí, te tenemos una sorpresa para tí...'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'Sobre mí',
      link: 'aboutme.html',
      href: 'Sobre mí'
    }, // Pendiente el texto
    {
      nombre: 'Contacto',
      link: 'contact.html',
      href: 'Contacto',
      text: 'Rellene el siguiente formulario para ser respondido y ayudarle. Nuestro servicio se extiende por todo el Ecuador.'
    },
    {
      nombre: 'Proyectos',
      link: 'projects/projects.html',
      href: 'Proyectos'
    }, // Pendiente el texto
    {
      nombre: 'D-grafix',
      link: 'projects/dgrafix.html',
      href: 'Proyectos | D-grafix'
    } // Pendiente el texto
  ]

  const filter = () => {
    result.innerHTML = '';
    const parameters = new URL(location.href);
    const text = parameters.searchParams.get("s").toLowerCase();

    for (let link of links) {
      const nombre = link.nombre.toLowerCase();
      if (nombre.indexOf(text) !== -1) {
        result.innerHTML += `<li><i class="bi bi-search" style="margin-right:10px;"></i><a href="${link.link}">${link.nombre} - ${link.href}</a><br><p class="lead mt-1 text-truncate" style="font-size:15px;max-width:350px;">${link.text || ''}</p></li>`
      }
    }

    if (result.innerHTML === '') {
      result.innerHTML +=
        `<li>No se han encontrado resultados...</li>`
    }
  }

  filter();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src = "main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container" id="formContainer">
            <h1 class="display-3 my-5">Búsqueda</h1>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="hero" id="divh1"></div> <!--Texto con el contenido: "Resultados de 'búsqueda'."-->
            </div>
            <div class="container mt-3 search">
                <div class="container"> 
                    <ul id="resultado"></ul>
                </div>  
            </div> <!--Resultados de la búsqueda-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Donde la magia ocurre aqui:

```
const parameters = new URL(location.href);
const text = parameters.searchParams.get("s").toLowerCase();
```

Como vemos creamos un objeto `URL` objeto el cual nos permitira usar luego ciertos metodos muy utiles como el metodo `searchParams` que te permite obtener el valor de un parametro de una peticion `GET`, ademas para obtener la `URL` actual usamos `location.href`, la cual nos devuelve nuestra `URL`.

De esta forma es como podemos obtener un parametro por `URL` que nos ha dado otra pagina.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el código que me mandaste ha funcionado, aunque tenga que leer bastante xd

Comment: @MatiasLaMota, si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como aceptada, así otros usuarios con problemas similares sabrán que puede ser útil para ellos también.